# Python Guessing Game

Tags: python, pythonista

For some reason the while loop never breaks as if userGuess is never becoming equal to compAnswer.  I have it printing the answer at the beginning so we know.  Done on Pythonista.

```
def guessing_game():
    compAnswer = random.randint(1,10)
    print compAnswer
    guesses = 1
    print "Okay, I\'m thinking of a number between 1 and 10."
    userGuess = raw_input("What number am I thinking of?:  ")
    while userGuess != compAnswer:
        userGuess = raw_input("Nope!  try again:  ")
        guesses += 1
    playAgain = raw_input("You got it!  My number was %s and it took you %d guesses.  Play again?:  " % (compAnswer, guesses))
    if playAgain == "yes":
        guessing_game()
    else:
        print "Okay bye!"
```

Comment: the use of recursion here is pointless instead of entering a new function, just use a `while` loop where `playAgain != "yes"`

Comment: oh yeah the thing had some functionality I was working on at the same time that needed other stuff too but I knew how to complete that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`compAnswer` is an integer, `userGuess` is a string; if you want them to be equal, use the same type:

```
while userGuess != str(compAnswer):
```

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it.  I forgot raw_input was string specific.

Answer (score 0):

compAnswer is a integer, while userGuess is raw_input() which accepts string value from the command line so they are not the same data type, so will never be == so it will keep looping.
Try this on the 6th line:

`userGuess = int(raw_input("What number am I thinking of?: "))`

but you the input you accept is always of numeric type, and this can break if they type non-numeric characters, so better yet, you can validate the user input by putting that line in a try block, and catch ValueError:

`try:
    userGuess = int(raw_input("What number am I thinking of?: "))
except ValueError:
    print "invalid input"`